# Solving coupled nonlinear PDEs, method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the coupled system:
$$\phi_t+y\phi_x=y,$$
$$y_t+yy_x=0,$$

which is a system that shows up in optics.

The equation for $y$ is the inviscid Burgers equation, which has solution

$$y=f(x-yt),$$
where $f(x)$ is the initial condition at $t=0$.

However, I do not know how to solve for $\phi$. Does anyone have any suggestions for approaching this problem?

Note, a related problem shows up in [this paper on optics](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.27.1393) (see $\S$ III).

Comment: Try the solution $\phi = f(x-yt) + x$.

Comment: Yes, more generally the solution is $\phi = g(x-yt)+x$, where $g(x)=\phi(x,0)$. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm going to post my comment as an answer, so the question doesn't look unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(x,t) = g(x-yt) + x$. Then $\phi$ satisfies $\phi_t + y \phi_x = y$. And
$$\phi(x,0) =g(x) + x \implies g(x) = \phi(x,0) -x$$
Assuming we are given $\phi(x,0)$, we have a solution.

However, I'm a bit bothered by the fact that I didn't use the second PDE, so I'll keep thinking about this.

Edit: I did sort of use the second PDE, in the sense that we don't know $g(x-yt)$ unless we use the second PDE to get y.

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi_t+y\phi_x=y$$

Let $\phi=\psi+x$
$$\psi_t+y(1+\psi_x)=y \quad\to\quad \psi_t+y\psi_x=0$$

$$\psi=F(x-yt)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

$$\phi=x+F(x-yt)$$

where $y(x,t)$ is the solution of the implicit equation : $\quad y=f(x-ty)$

Note that $F$ and $f$ are two independent functions (not the same in general).

This can be checked :

$\begin{cases}\psi_x=(1-ty_x)F' \\ \psi_t=(-y-ty_t)F' \end{cases} \quad\to\quad \psi_t+y\psi_x=(y_t+yy_x)(-t)F'=0\:$ because $\:y_t+yy_x=0$

Comment: I don't understand something here. If $\psi=\phi+x$, then $\phi=\psi-x$ and $\phi_t=\psi_t$ and $\phi_x=\psi_x-1$.

Comment: @Gert : Thanks to pointing out the typo, now corrected.